# Removing extra space on textfields

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

Is there a way to remove the extra spaces in every text field in blackberry 10? I dunno if its a default thingy to bb10, but there's always at least 10dp extra space below textfields

```
Container {
                leftPadding: 70
                rightPadding: 70
                topPadding: 60

                Container {
                    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                    layout: StackLayout {}

                    TextField {
                        id: tfFirstName
                        input.submitKey: SubmitKey.Next
                        hintText: qsTr("first name")
                        inputMode: TextFieldInputMode.Text
                    }

                    TextField {
                        id: tfLastName
                        input.submitKey: SubmitKey.Next
                        inputMode: TextFieldInputMode.Text
                        hintText: qsTr("last name")
                    }
```

Comment: This could also be due to the way the container applies the StackLayout to the fields. It seems suspicious that TextFields would take up more space than they need.

Comment: Can you show the issue on a screenshot?